# public int[][] GetArray() Says Illegal start of expression

Tags: java, image-processing

I'm trying to create a 2D array of an image in Java.

Here's what I have so far:

```
   public int[][] GetArray() {  //NetBeans is saying 'Illegal Start of Expression' on this line

        getimage data;
        getwidth;
        getheight;
        int[][] array = new int[width][height];

    for (loop through width) {
        for (loop through height) {
            array[q][p] = raster.getSample(p, q, 0);
        }
    }

    return array;
```

I tried setting the return part to:-

```
    return array[][];
```

but that produced an error saying cannot find symbol.

I'm relatively new to Java and I really want to get better quickly, if you could help me out, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Bother posting actual code?

Comment: Where is the illegal start of expression and how is array defined?

Comment: I don't want to post the code, as it's part of my degree course, I don't want to be caught out for plaigarism...

Comment: @DrYap I've defined it within main

Comment: @BenjaminFranklin Then form a look-alike code?

Comment: so how can we help you without the source code???? !!!!

Comment: OK, I'll edit it a bit, please bare with me!

Comment: @DrYap I've edited it now, what do you think?

Comment: Are you sure this method is not declared inside other method or outside class?

Comment: please paste the exact exception and at which line it happens.

Comment: @Apostolos it seems that it is not runtime exception but compile time error.

Comment: @Pshemo You're right, I can't run the program, it's in edit mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to return an array, do it like this

```
    return array;    // CORRECT
```

What you are doing is incorrect.

```
    return array[][];    // INCORRECT
```

Your function should look like this

```
public class MyClass
{ 

    // main is a method just like GetArray, defined inside class

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
          // do something
    }

    // other methods are defined outside main but inside the class.

    public int[][] GetArray() {

            int width = 5;   // change these to your dimensions
            int height = 5;

            int[][] array = new int[width][height]; 

            int q,p;

            for(q=0;q<width;q++)
            {
                 for(p=0;p<height;p++)
                 {
                     array[q][p] = raster.getSample(p, q, 0);
                 }
            }

        return array;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you return an `array` you should not use

`return array[][];`

you should not use the square brackets `[][]` . In the `return` statement we should not mention the dimensions of the array

instead use

`return array;` this is the correct way